# Scope on anonymous function

Tags: php, scope, anonymous-function

I had write a Router with anonymous function callback.

**Sample**

```
$this->getRouter()->addRoute('/login', function() {
    Controller::get('login.php', $this);
});

$this->getRouter()->addRoute('^/activate/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$', function($token) {
    Controller::get('activate.php', $this);
});
```

for smaller code, i want to move it to an Array.

I had write a Routing class with following methdos:

```
<?php
    namespace CTN;

    class Routing {
        private $path           = '/';
        private $controller     = NULL;

        public function __construct($path, $controller = NULL) {
            $this->path         = $path;
            $this->controller   = $controller;
        }

        public function getPath() {
            return $this->path;
        }

        public function hasController() {
            return !($this->controller === NULL);
        }

        public function getController() {
            return $this->controller;
        }
    }
?>
```

And my array has the routing paths with the new class:

```
foreach([
    new Routing('/login', 'login.php'),
    new Routing('^/activate/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$', 'activate.php');
] AS $routing) {
    // Here, $routing is available
    $this->getRouter()->addRoute($routing->getPath(), function() {

       // SCOPE PROBLEM: $routing is no more available
        if($routing->hasController()) { // Line 60
            Controller::get($routing->getController(), $this);
        }
    });
}
```

My current problem is (see the comments), the `$routing` variable is on the anonymous function not available.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function hasController() on null in /core/classes/core.class.php on line 60

how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a variable from the parent scope by using "use":

```
$this->getRouter()->addRoute($routing->getPath(), function() use ($routing) {

   // SCOPE PROBLEM: $routing is no more available
    if($routing->hasController()) { // Line 60
        Controller::get($routing->getController(), $this);
    }
});
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php , the part that starts with "Example #3 Inheriting variables from the parent scope"